# Why does apache2 module http2 not exist on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-14.04, http2

I'd like to install htt2_module. After a fresh installation of Ubuntu 14.04 following the steps listed in this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04), I have tried to enable the http2_module just running

```
sudo a2enmod http2
```

but I get: Module http2 does not exist!

the apache version installed is:Apache/2.4.7
,then as a workaround I tried with this [link](http://www.2daygeek.com/enable-http2-support-in-apache/) adding the following repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2
```

after refreshing with sudo apt-get update, and running again the command to install/enable the http2 I get the same error. Module http2 does not exist.

Answer (score 16):

Actually, http2 module is supported on apache 2.4.17 or higher (for better stability you should use at least 2.4.23) but default apache for Ubuntu 16.04 or 14.04 is lower than minimum required so in order to upgrade your apache 
follow below steps:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/apache2

$ sudo apt-key update

$ sudo apt-get update
```

then run

```
$ sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install apache2 -y
```

here you will be promted two times like :

> *** apache2.conf (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ?
>
> press Y both the times and proceed.

Check your mods-available folder you will see http2.load file

```
$ sudo a2enmod http2
```

you will get following output

> Enabling module http2. To activate the new configuration, you need to
>   run:   service apache2 restart

Comment: One more thing this process will reset all your configuration so keep the backup if required

Answer (score 8):

1. Upgrade Apache to Latest

   ```
   apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties 
   add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2 
   apt-get update -y 
   apt-get upgrade -y 
   apt-get install apache2 -y 
   apache2 -v
   ```

Apache version should be 2.4.25 or later.

2. Enable it from mod_http2

   ```
   a2enmod http2 
   service apache2 restart
   ```
3. Add Self-Signed OR Valid SSL to your website to enable http2 on your server.
   Link:- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-14-04
4. Add HTTP/2 Support to Apache2 Virtual Host file. Example :

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:443>  
       Protocols h2 http/1.1 
       ServerAdmin you@your-site.com 
       ServerName your-site.com 
       ... 
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

And Restart Apache2 Services

```
service apache2 restart
```

5. Apache2 on HTTP/2 does not support in mpm_prefork mode, change it to mpm_event.PHP version should be php5.6 or greater.

   ```
   service apache2 stop 
   apt-get install php7.1-fpm 
   a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif 
   a2enconf php7.1-fpm 
   a2dismod php7.1 
   a2dismod mpm_prefork 
   a2enmod mpm_event 
   service apache2 start
   ```

Now test your configuration by visiting your server's domain name or public IP address like this: https://server_domain_name_or_IP

To check the *HTTP/2* Protocol working or not, Go to Inspect Elements in your Browser and in Network Section you can check http protocol version.

Comment: I followed similar instructions to the DnA's answer above that I found on multiple sites, but Chrome steadfastly stuck with http1.1 no matter what I did. I finally found a page (https://techwombat.com/enable-http2-apache-ubuntu-16-04/) that prescribed installing php-fpm as also described here and things finally clicked into place. This should be the accepted answer right now IMO. Things will change in future of course, once Ubuntu adopts http2 support natively (the Apache project considers http2 support to be stable at this point in time, so hopefully that day is near enough.)

Comment: Yes @JohnRix 
Ubuntu is not supporting http2 natively, hopefully we'll get the stable release soon.

Answer (score 0):

I think upgrading apache2 only on Ubuntu 16.04 or Ubuntu 14.04 is unstable solve the case until you upgrade the OS to minimum ubuntu 18.04. In my case after upgrading apache2 only it show the anomaly that cant solve until I make fresh install ubuntu 18.04 for enabling HTTP/2 module.

I Hope this helps.