# Do I need to install/enable ALPN with HTTP2? How to do it for apache2 ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: http2, alpn

I just enabled http2 on my ubuntu 16.04 server. When I ran a test on https://tools.keycdn.com/http2-test it verifies that http2 is supported but also gives a warning that "ALPN is not supported".

Di I really need ALPN to take benifits of http2? If yes than how can I install it? I cannot find a way to install/enable/activate ALPN.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome demands ALPN for HTTPS as it has depreciated its predecessor (NPN): https://ma.ttias.be/day-google-chrome-disables-http2-nearly-everyone-may-31st-2016/

Other browsers still support HTTP/2 using NPN I believe (for now).

To use ALPN you need to compile your webserver with OpenSSL 1.0.2 or above. According to that link above Ubuntu 16.04 does support this.

Comment: I installed apache using apt-get install apache2 on 16.04 but the test is showing ALPN not supported. Is there a command to check on server itself?

Comment: Looks like Ubuntu doesn't yet support HTTP/2 on Apache (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes#HTTP.2F2_support_in_Apache_httpd) so how did you enable this?

Comment: Yes you are right. Ubuntu doesn't support HTTP/2 yet.  I installed using this answer on SO http://stackoverflow.com/a/37865176/1325686

Comment: What do you see in your error og when you restart as It should show the openssl version? Did you try "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade" to install all the latest updates?